# index value or create new column for dimensions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Main Tables have 5-25 columns and 1,000,000-100,000,000 rows, most of columns are FK to tables with less then 100 values like 'unique char(6)' and many views that perform calculations, joins and grouping need to show the user values like that original 'unique char(5)'.

In this case it is better to create tinyint identity(1,1) index column for each dimension table and join them to result of view or create and use indexes on original values like that  char(6)?

Comment: In general, smaller columns index better than larger columns, and numeric columns index faster than text columns (especially if the latter don't use a binary collation). But `TINYINT` is *very* small and limits your dimension to 256 values in total, forever -- and this includes values allocated but never used in the case of an  `IDENTITY`. Be certain that you can guarantee, from your data model, they'll never become larger, otherwise I wouldn't really feel comfortable with something smaller than `INT`. You may find that using row/page compression and columnstores are a far bigger win.

Answer (score 1):

You should test to see which works better.

However, it is quite reasonable to assume that dimension tables using `tinyint` *would* benefit performance, because they would significantly reduce the size of each row -- from 5 or 6 bytes  to 1.  This means that your large tables would fit on many fewer pages, reducing I/O time.

Balanced against this is the cost of the joins.  However, the reference tables would easily fit into memory.  And by making the lookup key the primary key on the table, the lookups would also be much faster.